# iOS and android template

Tags: android, ios

short question, is there a free mobile app template available? I’m very new to this so I don’t know much. I hear react native is the most common? If it is any consultation, I’m looking for a picture sharing format like iFunny.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to be more specific here.

As above mention, Android Studio has a few templates setup depending on your use and application, such as navigation view that allows you to switch to different fragments easily.

For Xcode, or iOS, you can check Apple Developer Document for some example code that might be useful for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android studio, there are a few templates for new activities/fragments. If you're looking for something that you can download and just change a few variables, it will probably take you longer/be more confusing than actually learning to program an app.

Each app has their native source code. For android it is java/kotlin, and iOS it is swift. React native is a framework to create your apps for both platforms at the same time(ish). Programming in the native languages vs using React has their own pros/cons, so it's up to you what you want to do.

If you are adamant on using a template, then a simple google of 'react native app templates' will probably be what you are looking for.

I personally recommend going the honest route and learning to program your app, it's not too difficult, and you will learn a lot!